# Gesture recognizer for windows phone8

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

hi Im new to windows phone 8 development.
I was searching for left swipe and right swipe using gesture recognizer but i cant able to trace out my actual requirement.Is there any possible ways available that would suit my requirement. 
Is there any methods available like in IOS or ANDROID for gesture recognizition for left swipe and right swipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Page()
{
    GestureListener gestureListener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(ContentPanel);
    gestureListener.DragCompleted += gestureListener_DragCompleted;
}

void gestureListener_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
{
    // User flicked towards left
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
        {
    }
    // User flicked towards right
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
        {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help....Itz working fine.I need some transition effect in case of swipping from left to right or right to left....Can anyone help me regarding this